# What are the maximum number of threads created in FixedThreadPool?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

Recently, I was asked to implement my own FixedThreadPool by my mentor. The pool must have at most, `N` fixed number of threads executing at a time. The Pool would also have mechanism where if it is full, Runnables would have to wait for others to finish. In java, we can achieve this using -

```
ThreadPoolExecutor tpe = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
tpe.execute(t1);
tpe.execute(t2);
tpe.execute(t3);
tpe.execute(t4);
```

In my implementation, I'm always creating a `new` Thread object and passing the supplied Runnables in it before starting it. So the total number of Threads that I create (using new keyword) are always equal to the number of Runnables. However, max counts of threads in running state would be as per `N` set by the user.

This implementation was rejected by my mentor and he explained me that the goal of Thread pool is to reuse the Threads, so you should create only `N` threads and ruse them for multiple Runnables.

But when I went inside the implementation of `ThreadPoolExecutor.execute` in native Java code I found out that it creates a new object for each Runnable using some kind of factory.

**Screenshot from java code**.

[image]

Now this somehow contradicts with the definition of ThreadPool which says that the threads are reused. Please clarify this as I am having a tough time to understand the concept (which is necessary to implement my own pool in correct way).

P.S. Please excuse my poor grammar

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code, rather copy-paste the code and state exactly which class you took it from. The constructor `Worker(Runnable firstTask)` is only called if the number of maximum threads is not yet reached, thus the name of the parameter (`firstTask`). This is in line with [the javadoc, which @mạnh-quyết-nguyễn posted in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50192343/4216641).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, from my point how the thread pool working algorithm would be similar  and looks like below

```
while (check if the pool is not shutdown) {
    Runnable task = pool.fetchTaskFromQueue(); // fetch the Task from the queue. In your case it object of MyRunnable class
    task.run(); // call the run() of MyRunnable object
}
```

Thread pool resues the `Thread`, not the `Runnable/ Callable` (Thread class is also an implementation of Runnable) implementation. So if you are passing an object of `Thread` in `ExecutorService#execute` it will never call `Thread#start` on the thread object which you have sent as the `argument` of the `execute`, it will only call the `Thread#run` from `ThreadPool's` own thread.

> What is the maximum number of threads created in FixedThreadPool?

-> Maximum no of thread Thread in ThreadPool will be 3 as per your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is document of `execute` function from `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor`

> ```
>      /*
>      * Proceed in 3 steps:
>      *
>      * 1. If fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, try to
>      * start a new thread with the given command as its first
>      * task.  The call to addWorker atomically checks runState and
>      * workerCount, and so prevents false alarms that would add
>      * threads when it shouldn't, by returning false.
>      *
>      * 2. If a task can be successfully queued, then we still need
>      * to double-check whether we should have added a thread
>      * (because existing ones died since last checking) or that
>      * the pool shut down since entry into this method. So we
>      * recheck state and if necessary roll back the enqueuing if
>      * stopped, or start a new thread if there are none.
>      *
>      * 3. If we cannot queue task, then we try to add a new
>      * thread.  If it fails, we know we are shut down or saturated
>      * and so reject the task.
>      */
> ```

So basically, if there are fewer than `corePoolSize` running threads or if old thread  died, new thread will be created. Otherwise, they're queued (using `LinkedBlockingQueue`)